# How to construct an internal hom functor for a closed monoidal category?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

I am studying closed monoidal category through Wikipedia and nLab. There could be misconceptions in my post. Please let me know in that case.

### Definition of a Closed Monoidal Category

Let $M$ be a symmetric monoidal category. $M$ is **closed** if and only if there are:

1. an assignment $[-,-]$, called an **internal hom** of $M$, sending each pair $(b,c)$ of objects in $M$ to some object $[b,c]$ in $M$, and each pair $(1_b,h)$ of morphisms in $M$ to some morphism $[1_b,h]$ in $M$, and
2. an assignment $\eta$, called **currying** of $M$, sending each triple $(a,b,c)$ of objects in $M$ to some function $\eta_{a,b,c}:\operatorname{Hom}(a\otimes b,c)\to\operatorname{Hom}(a,[b,c])$,

such that for all object $b$ in $M$:

1. $[b,-]$, sending $c$ to $[b,c]$ and $h$ to $[1_b,h]$, is a functor;
2. $\eta_{-,b,-}:\operatorname{Hom}(-\otimes b,-)\to\operatorname{Hom}(-,[b,-])$ is a natural isomorphism.

(I did not use the term "right adjoint" in the definition, but I know what it is, so you can use that concept in the answer.)

### Question

How does one prove that the internal hom above can be extended in a unique way to a functor $[-,-]:M^{\operatorname{op}}\times M\to M$ such that $\eta:\operatorname{Hom}(-\otimes-,-)\to\operatorname{Hom}([-,-],-)$ is a natural isomorphism?

### My Attempt

Let $g:b'\to b$ and $h:c\to c'$ be morphisms in $M$. We should define $[g,h]$, and then check that $[-,-]$ becomes a functor and $\eta$ becomes a natural isomorphism. The requirement that $\eta$ should be a natural transformation forces the following diagram to commute:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\operatorname{Hom}([b,c]\otimes b,c) @>{\eta_{[b,c],b,c}}>> \operatorname{Hom}([b,c],[b,c])\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\operatorname{Hom}([b,c]\otimes b',c') @>{\eta_{[b,c],b',c'}}>> \operatorname{Hom}([b,c],[b',c'])
\end{CD}
So there is only one way to define $[g,h]$. Namely,
\begin{equation}
[g,h] = \eta_{[b,c],b',c'}(h\circ(\eta_{[b,c],b,c}^{-1}(1_{[b,c]}))\circ(1_{[b,c]}\otimes g))\text{.}
\end{equation}

I proved that $[1_b,1_c]=1_{[b,c]}$ for all objects $b,c$ in $M$. But I could not prove that $[g',h']\circ[g,h]=[g\circ g',h'\circ h]$. Both sides of the equation becomes too messy when spelled out.

Comment: I think your diagram (and your formula for $[g^{\text{op}}, h]$) is slightly wrong -- the vertical morphisms should point the other way. Good work though, you have exactly the right idea for constructing the morphisms!

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Thanks. Instead of changing the diagram and the formula, I changed $g^{\operatorname{op}}$ to $g$. Sorry your answer should also be changed accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice work so far! I think breaking down the definition of this functor into smaller pieces will be helpful.

Given a morphism $g : b' \to b$ and an object $c$, we define $[g,1_c] : [b,c] \to [b',c]$ to be
$$\eta_{[b,c],b',c}(\eta_{[b,c],b,c}^{-1}(1_{[b,c]}) \circ (1_{[b,c]} \otimes g)).$$

Then we verify two conditions:

1. $[g_1 \circ g_2, 1_c] = [g_2, 1_c] \circ [g_1, 1_c]$ for all morphisms $g_1 : b' \to b$, $g_2 : b'' \to b'$, and all objects $c$.
2. $[1_{b'}, h] \circ [g,1_c] = [g, 1_{c'}] \circ [1_b, h]$ for all morphisms $g : b' \to b$ and $h : c \to c'$.

From these two facts it follows that defining $[g, h] = [g, 1_{c'}] \circ [1_b, h]$ makes $[{-},{=}]$ into a functor. This is general phenomenon: to define a functor $C_1 \times C_2 \to D$, you just need to describe the functoriality in each component and then check that they "commute" (in the sense of condition 2 above).

Unfortunately I don't have time to write a full answer right now, but I hope this helps you finish the proof -- the benefit of doing it this way is that you only have to deal with two morphisms (instead of four) at any time.

---

For condition 1, we equivalently need to verify that the following diagram commutes:

[image: Triangle diagram.]

(Check that this is really equivalent!). The three morphisms in this diagram also appeared in the commutative squares witnessing the naturality of $\eta$ (the square you drew in your post). So we paste those squares around the outside as follows:

[image: Big hexagon diagram with triangle in the middle]

Now check that the squares & triangles marked in red commute, and use the fact that the colored arrows are isomorphisms to deduce that the inner triangle commutes.

Apologies for the poor handwriting, I hope it's still understandable!

Comment: Thanks. But I do not know how to prove condition 1 in your answer. The equation still gets messy...

Comment: I've edited my post to give some direction there. For each condition, instead of working equationally, you should use the naturality squares that defined $[g,1]$ to build a large diagram that verifies the identity.

Comment: In your second diagram, shouldn't it be that, all the first argument is $[b,c]$, the second argument is one of $b,b',b''$, and all the third argument is $c$? I think I proved everything in my question this way. Anyway, thanks so much! I've been struggling on this problem for several days.

Comment: Oh yes you're absolutely right! I set up the diagrams the wrong way; sorry for the extra confusion.